# Find a permutation $(a_1,...,a_{10})$ of $(1,2,...,10)$ such that $ia_i \not\equiv ja_j \bmod 11$ for $2 \le i < j \le 10$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, permutations

(a) Find a permutation $(a_1,...,a_{10})$ of $(1,2,...,10)$ such that $a_1 \equiv 2a_2 \equiv \cdots \equiv 10a_{10} \bmod 11$.

(b) Find a permutation $(a_1,...,a_{10})$ of $(1,2,...,10)$ such that $ia_i \not\equiv ja_j \bmod 11$ for $2 \le i < j \le 10$.

---

(a) Since $11$ is prime we found the modular inverse of each numbers $(1,2,...,10)$ and paired them and all of them are $1 \bmod 11$.

This gives us the required permutation.

(b) Here I am stuck, I am not able to find a permutation.

Comment: Why not try the same problem for a smaller number?  Presumably the primality of $11$ is relevant, so take $5$ instead?  You could try $3$ but I expect it's too small to be interesting.

Comment: In this multiplicative group, there are $5$ squares and $5$ non-squares.

Comment: @RobertShore Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I just thought it might be a useful observation, but I don't have a clear proof strategy in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the product of all the residues mod 11 is equal to -1 mod 11. Now, notice that $\prod j a_j = \prod j \prod a_j \equiv -1 \times -1 = 1 \mod 11.$ But that means that it is not possible that $j a_j$ are all distinct. So, no such permutation exists.

Comment: They don't need to be *all* distinct.  One of them can duplicate $a_1$.  I think your original answer was correct, but you meant to say $ja_j=j^{-1}$.